# nano editor on macOS - How to Find and Replace

Tags: macos, homebrew, nano

On Linux, I'm used to using `^\` for find and replace.

On macOS, I'm getting this message: `[ Xterm mouse tracking on! ]`

If I press it again, it says `[ Xterm mouse tracking off! ]`

Rather than toggle Xterm mouse tracking, I would like to find and replace text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

`brew install nano`

`brew link nano`

Launch a new terminal window, `nano` will now allow find and replace using the method you are used to using.

Answer (score 1):

In some VPS is impossible to use “Ctrl + \”, instead you can use “Ctrl + W” and then “Ctrl + R”.